# Idiomatic way in Postgres to record when an event happened

Tags: postgresql

Consider an event with two states.

- Event did not occur, therefore there is no date of event occurrence.
- Event did occur, date exists when an event occurred.

Postgres has a type **timestamp**, is there a way to record the two states above with just the **timestamp** field where the `timestamp = not-set`, where not set is `0` or something, or do I also need a **boolean** field to differentiate between the two?

Comment: Sure, you can make the column nullable. But what is an event that didn't occur? Why are you storing things that don't exist in your database at all?

Comment: Would it be an option to set the **not set** column to **NULL**?

Comment: @Bergi, I would like to store when a password reset token was used.  If a token was issued and db entry was made and the user clicks on the link, I want to record when the token was used.

Comment: @user1135541 Ah, so the event is part of another entity (the token). Makes sense. Yes, use a nullable column.

Comment: OK, I looked it up, it makes sense, can one of you post an answer so I can mark it as an answer?